# how can I display summary of a link when posted

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building a micro blog app and I would like that once a link is posted in the text area and displayed on the show page, it will be converted into a brief summary with a title, image and brief description, just like it's done on Google+ and Facebook.

Is there a javascript or a rails gem that can handle this?

I am using bluecloth and markdown to handle the html attributes of the  links being posted through the textarea and I would like to know how to display the summary of the link or how to expand the links posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a neat jquery plugin to achieve this.

https://github.com/embedly/jquery-preview

Comment: Impressive. But is this free or there is a perticular paid version